# Evaluating Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

[image]

Answer choices:

22

15

10

358

None of the above

This is my solution:

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the answer is 10.

\begin{align*} 2^2 + 9^ \frac{1}{2} + 2^1 + 225^0 &= 4 + 9^ \frac{1}{2} + 2^1 + 225^0 \\
&= 4 + {\sqrt{9}} + 2^1 + 225^0 \\
&= 4 + 3 + 2^1 + 225^0 \\
&= 4 + 3 + 2 + 225^0 \\
&= 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 \\
&= 10
\end{align*}

Did some extended working out for you.